# Force open sharepoint URL instead of download

Tags: sharepoint

Am using D365 Powerautomate to generate Sharepoint history (document change history) urls , i can able to generate like below , but the problem is it is downloading the file instead i want to open the word document.

I have tried web=1 in the querystring, but no luck.

```
https://SITEURL/_vti_history/VERSIONID/LISTNAME/ROOTFOLDER/DOCNAME.docx
```

Url is perfect and downloading the right document , but i want to open in browser instead of download

Answer (score 1):

please use ?web=1 at the end of link, like this
https://SITEURL/_vti_history/VERSIONID/LISTNAME/ROOTFOLDER/DOCNAME.docx?web=1